# Performance Considerations of Microsoft Application Insights?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I couldn't find any information about an async implementation of application Insights, specifically the TelemetryClient for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights Nuget.

And by that I mean a full implementation from the exposed methods down to the actual http request sent to the service, not just a wrapper.

I guess it'd make sense for performance considerations, especially when coding a ASP.NET MVC website.   Is that on the roadmap? Did I miss anything?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks Mark! I may have skipped this one, decompiling the code they're indeed doing everything on a separate thread.
I guess having that on a totally separate thread versus having async tagging all the way along to have the TaskScheduler properly handle everything doesn't make a huge difference performance wise then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The article about the [application insights overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-overview/) has a section **What's the overhead?**

which describes the performance gap produced by application insights as following:

> *The impact on your app's performance is very small. Tracking calls are non-blocking, and are batched and sent in a separate thread.*

So you don't have to consider about performance issues caused by application insights.

Comment: `sent in a separate thread` --> can some one show me a way to verify this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks that's true!

Please, see image:

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).